# Using whereInStrict() in laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, where-in

I tried using `whereIn()` in my project but because of its loose comparison it considered a value '1gb' as integer. So as per the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-whereinstrict) I used `whereInStrict()`.

```
$spec['vals'] = ['1 gb', '2gb', '8gb']; // array created by explod()     
ProductSpecification::whereInStrict('value', $spec['vals'])->get();
```

But the creates sql query like **"Select * from product_specifications where in_strict = 'value' "**, thus giving an error. What to do? Am I using it wrong?

I'm kinda new to laravel.

Comment: `whereInStrict` is a method of collection, you cannot use it for queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a collection of the `ProductSpecification`, so first get all and then use `whereInStrict`.

```
$spec['vals'] = ['1 gb', '2gb', '8gb'];
ProductSpecification::all()->whereInStrict('value', $spec['vals']);
```